# How can I select an image inside of a div to change its source?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have the following div and I know the selector Id of the DIV.

```
 <div class="event"><img src="/Content/Images/Icons/calendar16.png">Event Name</div>
```

but I don't know, what the image is. I need something to find the image selector inside the div, that I have. So I can go change the source of the image to a new image.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('.event').children('img').attr('src', '<source here>');
```

This selects all the elements with the `event` class and then finds their children `img` elements. If you have multiple matches and want to change their sources differently then you can use `$.each()` to iterate through them.

- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children
- `.attr()` : http://api.jquery.com/attr

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aPzgR/

Answer (score 10):

```
$('div.event img').attr('src', '/anything');
```

If you have several divs with `event` as the class you're better off selecting the div by id if you don't want to change the source of all the images