# Adding different description to images opened in bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already found ([Bootstrap open image in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal)) how to open images in modals but I need more functionality.

1) I need to add different description to each photo

2) I want to modal window will be max. full height of screen not 100% of photo...

Here is example.

I want that 3 lines (with description in footer) to change with every image.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" data-dismiss="modal">
  <div class="modal-content"  >              
    <div class="modal-body">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
         <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
    </div> 
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
       <p class="text-left">1. line of description<br>2. line of description <br>3. line of description</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
});     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ve4hbmm/

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2ve4hbmm/2/)

> 1) I need to add different description to each photo

To add your descriptions to the photo, you can use data attributes to store the text or html that you want to add for each image.  In my example, I used 3 separate data attributes to set a title, description and source for each image as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="pop" data-title="Turkish Van Cat" data-desc="The Turkish Van is a semi-long-haired breed of domestic cat, which was developed in the United Kingdom from a selection of cats obtained from various cities of modern Turkey, especially Southeast Turkey." data-source="<strong>Source</strong> Wikipedia">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</a>
```

Then you can easily retrieve the value of the data attribute using the **[jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** method.

```
$('.pop').on('click', function () {
    //Get the value of the data-title attribute
    var title = $(this).data('title'); 
    //Get the value of the data-desc attribute
    var desc = $(this).data('desc');
    //Get the value of the data-source attribute
    var source = $(this).data('source');
    //Add the title text to the container with the title class
    $('.title').text(title);
    //Add the desc text to the container with the desc class
    $('.desc').text(desc);
    //Add the source *html* to the container with the source class
    $('.source').html(source);
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
});
```

You place text with the jQuery **[text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method, but if you're adding html, like I did to make the word "Source" bold in the data-source attribute, you need to use the JQuery **[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method. Both methods work the same in that they will replace the contents of the target entirely.  I created three separate targets with a class of `.title`, `.desc` and `.source` accordingly in the html of your modal.

```
<div class="img-description">
  <p class="text-left title"></p>
  <p class="text-left desc"></p>
  <p class="text-left source"></p>
</div>
```

> 2) I want to modal window will be max. full height of screen not 100%
>   of photo...

There are a couple of different ways to approach this, and a few challenges if your images are of different height/width ratios and your text is an unknown length.  To address these issues, instead of overriding the `.modal-footer` class, I just created a new class of `.img-description` which I place absolutely relative to the modal-body.

The trick to getting the modal to be 100% of the screen height/width is to override the `.modal-dialog` class and position it absolutely.  The image container, which has a class of `.img`, is given a height of 80%, so you can set the max-height of the image itself to 100% to make it fill the space vertically.

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.modal-content, .modal-body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-description {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.img {
  height: 80%;
}
.imagepreview {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The html for the modal now looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                <div class="text-center img">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive imagepreview" />
                </div>
                <div class="img-description">
                    <p class="text-left title"></p>
                    <p class="text-left desc"></p>
                    <p class="text-left source"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```