# Bootstrap 3 open an Image in a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a table where a user has to click the image to view it in a modal, I am following the instructions here [Bootstrap open image in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal) because we have the same case, and on JSFiddle, his code works fine, but to me, it doesnt work, My code is like this:

```
<div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Products Table</h3>                                    
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Brand Name</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                    <th>Stocks</th>
                                    <th>Expiry Date</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $query = mysql_query("select * from product,product_brand where product_brand.product_brand_id = product.product_brand_id") or die(mysql_error());
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    $user_id = $row['product_id'];
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_brand_name']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_description']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_price']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_stock']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo   $row['product_exdate']; ?></td> 
                                        <td><a href="#" id="pop">
 <img id="imageresource" src="<?php echo $row['prod_image']; ?>" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
 Click to Enlarge  </a>
```

On the image I decided to put the modal, so when it's click, the image is inlarge in the modal, I also wanted the image to be hidden, how should i do it?
now, this code is for the modal and the script,which is sad to say, it doesnt seem to appear?:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> View</h4>
                </div>



                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Discard</button>


                    </div>

                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
 <script>
 $("#pop").on("click", function() {
 $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src')); // here asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
 $('#imagemodal').modal('show'); // imagemodal is the id attribute assigned to the bootstrap modal, then i use the show function <img src=""  id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: mysql_ in php syntax is deprecated

Comment: In your second snippet you haven't initialized jquery, have you?

Comment: what do u mean by that?

Comment: All your jquery code should be wrapped around
$(document).ready(function(){
   // do jQuery
}) or (function(){
   // do jQuery
})(jQuery)