# This is my code in php with Bootstrap to show image in the page .It's Working fine but I want to add pop up image with bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code in php with Bootstrap to show image in the page which are saved in folder.It's Working fine but I want to add pop up image with bootstrap . Like Bootstrap Modal. Is there any suggestion or might be a code for how to do it...!! Thanks.

```
<?php
    $path = 'images/gallery/';  // Create initial "Folders" array
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $_POST['type']='all';
    if($_POST['type']!='all'){
        $classloop[] = $_POST['type'];
        $folders[]=ucfirst($_POST['type']);
        $start=0;                            
        $foldercount = count($folders)-1;
    }else{
        if ($dir = opendir($path)) {

            $j = 0;
            while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {

                if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($path.$file)) {
                    $j++;

                    $folders[$j] = $file;
                }

            }
        }
    $classloop = array("","","resort","envato");
    $start=1;
    $foldercount = count($folders);
}
for ($i = $start; $i <= $foldercount ; $i++){
    $folderpath = $path.$folders[$i];
    $images = glob($folderpath."/".$filetype);
    $count = count($images);
    if($count>0){
        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {?>
        <?php
            $z = $j%3;

            echo '<div class="'.$folders[$i].' photo-item hover test" style="float:left;position:unset !important;">';
            echo '<a href="'.$images[$j].'" class="image-box">';
            echo '<div class="photo">';
            echo '<span class="text"><span class="anchor"></span></span>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<img src="'.$images[$j].'" alt=""  width="260"  height="170"/>';
            echo ' </a></div>';
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto">';
            echo '<img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />';
            echo '</a></div>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div align="center" style="width: 100%;">No image(s) found</div>'
    }
}
?>
```

here is my html code:

```
<section id="content-area">
<div class="container">
<div class="inner-content">
<h3>Photo Gallery</h3>
<ul id="categories">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall1('Resort');" class="Resort active">name1</a>
</li>
<li class="rooms">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall1('Rooms');" class="Rooms">name2</a>
 </li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall1('Dinning');" class="Dinning">name3</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall1('Swiming-Pool');" class="Swiming-Pool">name4</a>
 </li>
<li class="last">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall1('all');" class="all">View all</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="row gallery">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="gphoto"><img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please reformat if possible.

Comment: what trouble you are getting in the code?

Comment: Please format it with proper indentation.

Comment: Really Unreadable code. Can you make it little bit readable before posting. No coding standards.

Comment: Please add HTML so can check

Comment: i have uploaded html code, please check that.

Comment: Please check the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal

Comment: thanks for the link but with my php code when i put an image in the folder, it appears on the webpage.So how do i integrate bootstrap code with this php code???