# Give lightbox effect to images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a lightbox effect on every image. When I click an image, it must be enlarged (on the same page) and when I click at any part of the webpage *except* the image, the image must close.

```
<div class="row jumbotron">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">

            <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">

               <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <img height="180px" src="images/a.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try a tutorial: https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery

Comment: Removed filler text and unnecessary image, text edits

Comment: If you are using bootstrap css and js then Please see this [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal)

Answer (score 0):

Nice and easy with bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="*insert image*" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".lightbox"/>
        <div class="modal lightbox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <img src="*insert image*" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```