# Bootstrap Open Image in Modal having dynamic image src

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My question is regarding this answer. [Bootstrap open image in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal)

How can I display images that's src comes from MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

simply `echo` the img source from the database.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['profile_id'])){
     var uid=$_POST['profile_id'];
     $result->query("SELECT profile FROM user WHERE uid=$uid");
     $row=$result->fetch_array();
     die(json_encode($row));
  }
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="pop">
  <img src="" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>
```

**Jquery Part:**

```
$.post("ajax.php",{profile_id:1},function(response){
   if(response){
     var profileImg=JSON.parse(response);
         profileImg=profileImg[0].profile;
         $('.pop img').attr('src','http://example.com/image/'+profileImg);
         $('.pop').modal('show');
   }
});
```

Comment: Sarath I know the PHP part. I want to know how to display images in modal using jquery and bootstrap.