# Bootstrap popup modal for multiple images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am referring to this tutorial about modal image [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img).

The example show ONE image, which when clicked on, pops up in a modal. Some JavaScript is involved and I am not quite familiar with JavaScript.

If instead of this line:

```
<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
```

,I have multiple images (say 4) arranging like below:

```
<img id="myImg1" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img id="myImg2" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img id="myImg3" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img id="myImg4" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
```

how do I modify this code (and maybe the JavaScript) so that the modal popup shows the respective image that is clicked on?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Creating one modal for each image seems like a very crude way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't shown your JS, but wherever you handle the click that opens the modal you need to a) find the image that was clicked; b) insert that into the modal; c) open the modal.  There are many examples here on SO, eg:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/in-bootstrap-open-enlarge-image-in-modal

Comment: @Don't Panic Thanks for the reference. It really helps.